# Problem with onturnasync of middleware in bot framework v4

Tags: c#, botframework, middleware

I am facing problem with `OnTurnAsync()` method of middleware. I have almost integrated Middleware Bot sample of human handoff provided by tompanna in my existing  Bot but still `OnTurnAsync()` method in Middleware has not being called on message activity.

Ideally Middleware `OnTurnAsync()` need to be executed first and then the bot `OnTurnAsync()`. In our case bot `OnTurnAsync()` is called on every message activity. Can any one having idea about it?

Comment: Can you add the part on how you have added the middleware in your bot code? Also, the sample which you are supposedly using was last updated almost a year back. I would suggest you to get started with the experimental handoff bot [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/handoff-library/csharp_dotnetcore/samples/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.HandoffBot)

Comment: There is also a really good Human Handoff Bot [sample](https://github.com/tdurnford/botframework-human-handoff) by TJ Durnford in Node which you can take a look at as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're talking about [this](https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample/blob/master/IntermediatorBotSample/Middleware/HandoffMiddleware.cs) sample, just to be clear.

I haven't looked into it in great detail, but conceptually, the idea behind this is that it will only "handoff" when the certain condition is met (i.e. if the message from the user contains the word "human"). **Only in this case** will the bot actually "process" the message (by passing it on to a human operator). In all other cases, it assumes that your bot itself **is meant to handle** the message (i.e. the Turn). Essentially, the sample is helping your bot to "escalate" **certain** messages to a human operator, not **every** message. Are you trying to do something different in your bot? Is -every- message supposed to go to the human operator?

Comment: I would suggest you to ask clarifying questions in the comments and then post an answer accordingly(posting answers along with questions can be quite confusing for other users)